# How to make dynamic chart with the next view? What libraries allows to customise exactly this like in my design?

Tags: charts, highcharts, chart.js

I have never worked with charts before so I'm a little blind here,

I want to ask the guys who worked with charts enough to recommend me the library for building charts which allows to customize charts exactly like in my desig below

It would be good to use vue.js for this, so if you know such vue.js chart packages it would be perfect!

Check the design of the graph:

[image]

***Pay attention - there's kind of changing chart line color (the part of line which is below is red and the one above is green)***

Thank you guys a lot for any recommendation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create that type of chart in a simple way by using Highcharts.

In case of any problems you can get help on support channels: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/support/

Highcharts also has officially supported `vue` wrapper, which can be useful in your case: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-vue

You can start from:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [...],
        zones: [{
            value: 0,
            color: 'red'
        }]
    }],
    navigator: {
        enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        inputEnabled: false
    },
    scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vknsb7rw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.zones

Comment: Hey ppotaczek, it is really usefull information, thank you! 
I appreciate this but when I checked pricing page of HightCharts they want 720$ for the year of using. I use only one chart for the page and pay 720$/year is too much I think. Do you know if there're similar solutions??

Comment: Hi @Taras Chernata, I'm sorry but I don't know other charting libraries.